# Stochastic integral is a bounded operator?

Tags: stochastic-processes, hilbert-spaces, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, unbounded-operators

### The Setup

Let $\xi_t$ be a process adapted to the filtration $\mathfrak{F_t}$ of the semi-martinagale $X_t$, such that both are square integrable.  Then is the map
\begin{align}
F_T: L^2(\Omega\times[0,T],\mathfrak{F_t},\mathbb{P}\times m) \rightarrow & L^2(\Omega,\mathfrak{F},\mathbb{P}),\\
\xi_t \mapsto & \int_0^T \xi_tdX_t
\end{align}
where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure and $(\Omega,\mathfrak{F},\mathfrak{F}_t,\mathbb{P})$ is a stochastic base for the process $X_t$.  The norms are defined as
$$
\|\xi_t\|^2_2 \triangleq \mathbb{E}[\int_0^T\xi_t^2d\mu(t)]\, and \, \|X\|^2_2\triangleq \mathbb{E}[X^2], 
$$
where $\xi_t$ is in the domain of $F_T$ and $X$ in it's codomain.

### The Question

For any given $T>0$ is the map $F_T$ a continuous operator, as it is clearly $\mathbb{R}$-linear?  If not is it at least closed or bounded?

*Note:*  Ultimately, my goal is to obtain some sort of boundedness result.

Comment: Would you mind explicitly defining the two $L^2$ norms you have in mind here?

Comment: Hi Cameron, I have put in those details, thanks.

Comment: Unless $\mu$ (or $m,$ you should choose one) is $d<X>_t$ I don't see why the integral should be defined. But if this is the case, then the operator is bounded because you have an isometry (it is actually the Ito isometry).

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/252359/stochastic-integral-is-a-continous-or-closed-operator